# Access Middle-ware applied for a given route Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to access the middlewares applied for a specific route.
I'm getting the middleware for current route, but not for a specific route other than current.

This will return middleware of current route

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getFacadeRoot()->current()->computedMiddleware;
```

I want to access the middleware of this route

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes()->getByName('task_details');
```

The `computedMiddleware` of this route returns null. I applied a couple of middlewares for this route.

Anyone have any idea about this?.
Or anyother workarounds?

Comment: What is the returned type of `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes()->getByName('task_details');` is it `Illuminate\Routing\Route` ?

Comment: @Maraboc Yes, it returning `illuminate\Routing\Route`

Comment: This is the output
`Route {#163 ▼
  +uri: "tasks/{id}"
  +methods: array:2 [▼
    0 => "GET"
    1 => "HEAD"
  ]
  +action: array:7 [▶]
  +controller: null
  +defaults: []
  +wheres: []
  +parameters: null
  +parameterNames: null
  +computedMiddleware: null
  +compiled: CompiledRoute {#223 ▶}
  #router: Router {#21 ▶}
  #container: Application {#2 ▶}
}`

Comment: Ok then test this function `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes()->getByName('t‌​ask_details')->gatherMiddleware();` !!

Comment: It gives all middleware, including the ones from the controller.  ;)